# JQuery Flot: Just pan when holding the Shift key

Tags: javascript, jquery, flot

In flot i want to pan the graph just while the shift key is pressed.
I tried to change the flot.navigate plugin the following way (just changed the `bindEvents` function):

```
if (o.pan.interactive) {
     $(document).keydown(function(e){
          if(e.shiftKey == 1){
            eventHolder.bind("dragstart", { distance: 10 }, onDragStart);
            eventHolder.bind("drag", onDrag);
            eventHolder.bind("dragend", onDragEnd);
          }
       })
      }
```

This works for the first time i press shift but then the browser is not responding for some reason.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With your code the binding is only done when shift is pressed, not the drag-and-drop itself. Instead change the `onDragStart(e)` function like this:

Original:

```
    function onDragStart(e) {
        if (e.which != 1)  // only accept left-click
            return false;
        var c = plot.getPlaceholder().css('cursor');
        ...
```

New:

```
    function onDragStart(e) {
        if (e.which != 1 || e.shiftKey != 1)  // only accept left-click + pressed shiftkey
            return false;
        var c = plot.getPlaceholder().css('cursor');
        ...
```